# Redirections Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to control the redirection without modifying the HTML code

The content of the page is returned Webservice and all the URLs are redirected to other tabs, and I have no control over HTML

Is there a way to force all redirects in the same page?

Comment: The content of the page contains a URL redirection (href)
When I click on this URL, it will open on the same page
I want these URLs to open in a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the anchors of the website and add a `target` property with the value `_blank`.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

### Relevant part:

Specifies where to display the linked URL. It is a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context: a tab, window, or `<iframe>`. The following keywords have special meanings:

- `_self`: Load the URL into the same browsing context as the current one. This is the default behavior.
- `_blank`: Load the URL into a new browsing context. This is usually a tab, but users can configure browsers to use new windows instead.
- `_parent`: Load the URL into the parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this behaves the same way as `_self`.
- `_top`: Load the URL into the top-level browsing context (that is, the "highest" browsing context that is an ancestor of the current one, and has no parent). If there is no parent, this behaves the same way as `_self`.

```js
(function($) {
  $('a').each(function(idx, element) {
      element.target = '_blank';
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='https://google.pt/'>Google</a>
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a>
```